# 最も有名なのがウーロン茶で : What is the usage of なの here?

Tags: words

What is the usage of `なの` in:

`最も有名なのがウーロン茶で`

To me, it seems to transfer a `adverb [有名]` to a `noun`, is that so? Could someone help to explain, thx.

---

**Update:**

To make the question more clear, the whole sentence is:

`日本で中国茶として最も有名なのがウーロン茶で、`

Answer (score 4):

The predicative form of `有名` is `有名だ` and its attributive or adjectival form is `有名な`. The `の` particle nominalizes (changes) the preceding adjective into a noun.

So 最も有名な**`の`**がウーロン茶で

is saying that the most famous `thing` is oolong tea.

Comment: I don't think this post deserves downvote, though I would explain that the の is simply a pronoun.

Comment: But I am not yet **sure**. 有名校 can not be explained only with the function of the na-adjective. 有名, Kanji, noun itself is an adjective, I think.

Comment: Because, when I take 有名 as a noun and the な as the 連体形 of the auxiliary だ, then it ( 有名 ) can be **more flexible**. For example, 有名かも,
有名らしい,有名なり etc, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I forgot that 有名 is used sometimes as a kanji compound.